# Migrating Blender related questions from other SE sites?

Tags: discussion

Will there be some time soon an effort to migrate blender related questions from other SE sites? I.e. Stackoverflow is full of 'em, and I'd imagine it'd be good to consolidate those into one place.

Comment: Most likely not (at least for the existing ones), but when we get into public beta, new questions probably will be.

Answer (score 9):

While it's *technically* possible to migrate questions, the migration paths are not set up until a site becomes well-established.

But beyond that technical limitation, building this community from the old, pre-answered questions of another site would do ***this*** site a terrible disservice. **That's not how you want to build this site.**

Forget for a moment that other site may not *want* their content removed like that (along with the the knowledge and reputation earned). Consider that, from day one, your brand new site will be **filled with old, pre-answered "anonymous" questions — remember, the  original authors are off on *another* site.**

So, unless Blender questions have been deemed off topic on another site, we will not be migrating another site's content here.

[Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)

I wouldn't start out this site by glomming off the content built by others. It would be very difficult to build a comprehensive, functional community by migrating a bunch of questions *en masse.*

I would also be really careful about trawling other communities for their users/posts. Unless a particular question is being closed as *off topic*, please don't start soliciting users to bring their content elsewhere. That would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that we should definitely transfer all the Blender-related questions we can, in order to help direct users to our site. In particular, I've noticed a significant number of Blender questions on:

- Stack Overflow
- Game Development
- Ask Ubuntu

Comment to this post if you know of another SE site with a lot of Blender content.

Comment: Posts on those sites' metas would be helpful in this aspect.

Comment: But on Gamedev, they have questions related to the Blender game engine. Would we still migrate those?

Comment: @DantheMan Blender is Blender, it would also depend. I don't think they handle technical issues.

Answer (score 1):

Encouraged by this discussion I asked [Setup of PyDev and Eclipse for Blender Add-Ons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/351/setup-of-pydev-and-eclipse-for-blender-add-ons) now this question is likely to get closed as off-topic.

After it has been closed I will simply post it on SO. Anyway it represents a type of question that seems suitable to define the limits of on-topic.

Update:

The post on SO was ignored (no upvotes, less views): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821865/setup-of-pydev-and-eclipse-for-blender-add-ons

At here it has currently 5 upvotes which indicates that more users than me have an interest to get this solved. having that said we could rethink whether questions like that should be on-topic.

Comment: Although I am not opposed to the idea of concentrating questions like yours on this site, I am not sure it will attract the needed attention of programmers as it could on SO.

Comment: Re: update, keep in mind that this was in private beta where votes were flying around. Try bumping the post on SO to see if it gets any new hits. I am somewhat inclined to agree however since the last meta post related to _[external-applications]_. At the same time however, seeing that programming questions are already borderline and we are talking about an entire different package from CG here (an IDE), I still think that this might be out of the scope of this site.

Comment: @iKlsR It was a recent upvote of the closed question which awoke me. What a shame that there is no place to ask something like that.

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer to [Migration path to Blender.SE](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1178/25712) posted on [GameDev.se](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) meta, the migration paths are setup based on how common manual migrations are.

Therefore, if you are a member of another stack exchange site, and you see a new question that is suitable for [Blender.SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) you can flag it with **other** and ask that it is migrated.

As stated in [previous](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/87/235) answers, migrating old content is not to be encouraged.

But is a question is off topic for the other site, but about blender, you could consider migrating it.