# What are we doing wrong that we're still in Beta?

Tags: discussion, graduation

So an earlier [answer](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/107/2217) in the Blender meta site seemed to suggest that 1500 visitors per day was a desirable goal. If I read the stats for the Blender site correctly, were have more than 10,000 visitors per day, and we've apparently been in beta status since some time in 2013. What other hoops do we need to jump through here?

Comment: And now moderator elections are in the works and we are officially in the qeue :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do not think we are doing anything "wrong." SE sites can take a long time to graduate.
If you look at the stats of the other sites, we are in a good place. We actually place ahead of several full sites. The time in beta does not mean anything. The old 90 day limit has been done away with. Now the SE team looks at each beta site and lets it grow until it has a sufficient base of higher rep users.

If our nearly 2 years in beta has you worried, don't be. There are **55** beta sites that are older then us. Also, of the sites around the same age as us, our stats are *much* better.

Look through the different data points on the sites (and use the sort box) http://stackexchange.com/sites you will see we are in good shape.

However obsessing over the stats is discouraged, at nearly ever place site graduation is talked about.
So keep using the site, get more rep, and don't worry when that day comes. (I for one don't mind being in beta at all)

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/
[Good explanation of the graduating review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242072/278094)

Comment: I'm not worried. I just thought if we were needing to send in soup can labels, or cereal box tops to uprade the status, I wanted to be sure I was participating.

Comment: @brasshat lol. no box tops needed :)

Comment: @David You forgot to note that one of the community managers said we were in the queue for graduation (unless I missed an update). The comment is somewhere on meta.se

Comment: @brasshat if you go by the stats on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40377/blender) we are only low on two stats - answered and answer ratio - the more questions you answer the more you help. I do think answered we can (and should) improve, but I'm not sure that answered ratio will improve a lot as some of our questions will only get one answer. Another thing I do is watch other SE sites with blender tags, answer and flag some as more suitable for this site, this not only gives us more questions but sends more users to the right place for future questions.

Comment: Excellent answer. I should also add that graduation depends not only on stats, but other seemingly minor things such as having a theme for the site (for example).