# Should we migrate questions from GD?

Tags: discussion, migration

There are lots of questions being asked on Graphic Design which would fit perfectly on this site.

For example:

- [Blender - how are points and paths imported from svg different from points and paths created in Blender?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/6463/14863)
- [How to create wireframes in Blender 3D](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17814/14863)
- [Rendering only the edges in Blender 2.6x - wireframe with thicker lines](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/4784/14863)

. . . and [many more](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender).

Should these kinds of questions be migrated over here in the future? It seems to me that while they might not be off-topic on GD, it would be better to keep blender questions on blender.stackexchange. Otherwise, what is the point of having a site specifically for blender questions?

---

I have seen [Migrating Blender related questions from other SE sites?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/68/599), but it seems to be targeted at migrating existing questions.

---

## **Update**:

As mentioned by Ryan in the comments, there is now [this post on GD meta](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1122/14863).

So far it seems like the GD community is okay with migrating new blender questions over here. Are we okay with this too?

I don't see anything wrong with this (plus I imagine it's good for getting the word out about us, to say nothing of having some extra questions), but I have some questions of my own.

For example, if a question is asked on GD which already has an answer here, should it still be migrated (and then closed as a duplicate)?

Will this confuse users who have there questions shuffled around and then closed?

Or am I just making mountains out of molehills?

Comment: Some of your arguments are invalid, with that logic, we should remove our python tag and ask python questions on SO only. There are multiple flavours of language SE sites, religion etc. To each _specific_ user group their own, Blender questions fit here but it's a multi-purpose tool, it can be used elsewhere. We shouldn't be selfish.

Comment: Well, we do to an extent. Python questions which are not related to blender are migrated (or closed as off-topic).

Comment: I just posted this on the Graphic Design Meta, we welcome input from you all: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1122/blender-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's already answered on that site, it makes no sense. GD and many of these sites have a tag for Blender so it is allowed to an extent and these sites might not want their content removed.

Also, if a question is older than a week or two, it's not worth migrating as we don't want to clutter our site with old unwanted garbage for the most part and the user might not come over as well. I constantly poke around other SE sites where Blender is tag and one thing I notice is that the question quality is *significantly* lower than those that get asked here and in those examples above, most of those are a query away on the front page of google or even the relevant wiki page.

As Robert [says](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/87/12):

> But beyond that technical limitation, building this community from the old, pre-answered questions of another site would do this site a terrible disservice. That's not how you want to build this site.

So I don't think we should actively go around looking for things to migrate, if it's not on-topic on another SE site, they will probably send it here and we can take it from there.

It is also well worth noting that we are doing extremely well in terms of questions, we have had a 12+ average per day for nearly 2 months now. Questions are not our problem at the moment, we should focus on consistency and quality and improving our answer ratio. If you want more questions to answer, browse the [*Unanswered* tab](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). ;)

Comment: Okay. I was mostly talking about migrating new, unanswered questions (as yet unasked), and just used those existing, answered posts of examples of the kinds of questions they are likely to be.

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, I figured but as I said, other sites want their content as well. If it's not ontopic there, they know we exist. I've seen multiple comments on SO directing people here. Also, sites such as gamedev and graphicdesign seem to get only 1 - 3 questions every month.

Comment: Also relevant to this discussion — [Respect the community — your own and others'](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).